# Update Ubuntu on my notebook

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

Goodevening, i have a notebook with Ubuntu 16.04 in dual boot with win10. I want to upgrade my Ubuntu to 20.04 with a new installation but my trouble Is where to install the bootloader.

Can someone help me?? Thank you
[image]

Comment: FYI:  The *bootloader* goes to a drive/device and not partition; your `gparted` image shows only partitions (*which includes a small ESP being sdb2, but if it was me I'd not use that due to small size; I'd check what you're using now & go by that*)

Comment: Thank you for replies. 'Why not boot your current 16.04 & see what is being used & how.' --> how can i do to check what i'm using now?